# Replace second occurrence of a string in one column based on value in other column in R

Tags: r, regex, string, find-occurrences

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
a <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse")
b <- c("my cat is a tabby cat and is a friendly cat", "walk the dog", "the mouse is scared of the other mouse")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I'd like to be able to remove the second occurrence of the value in col a in col b.

Here is my desired output:

```
a      b
cat    my cat is a tabby and is a friendly cat
dog    walk the dog
mouse  the mouse is scared of the other
```

I've tried different combinations of gsub and some stringr functions, but I haven't even gotten close to being able to remove the second (and only the second) occurrence of the string in col a in col b. I think I'm asking something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191318/regex-match-second-occurrence-of-a-string-in-perl) one, but I'm not familiar with Perl and couldn't translate it to R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this...

```
library(stringr)
df$b <- str_replace(df$b, 
                    paste0("(.*?",df$a,".*?) ",df$a), 
                    "\\1")

df
      a                                       b
1   cat my cat is a tabby and is a friendly cat
2   dog                            walk the dog
3 mouse        the mouse is scared of the other
```

The regex finds the first string of characters with `df$a` somewhere in it, followed by a space and another `df$a`.  The capture group is the text up to the space before the second occurrence (indicated by the `(...)`), and the whole text (including the second occurrence) is replaced by the capture group `\\1` (which has the effect of deleting the second `df$a` and its preceding space).  Anything after the second `df$a` is not affected.

Comment: @carozimm Note that my solution and G5W's solution do different things. Mine compares each `df$b` only to the `df$a` in the same row, whereas the other answer compares `df$b` to ALL words in the `df$a` column (so it will delete "dog" in "that cat is not a dog", for example).  My solution also avoids leaving an extra space where the deleted word was.  Hopefully this is the behaviour you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little work to build the right Regex.

```
P1 = paste(a, collapse="|")
PAT = paste0("((", P1, ").*?)(\\2)")

sub(PAT, "\\1", b, perl=TRUE)
[1] "my cat is a tabby  and is a friendly cat"
[2] "walk the dog"                            
[3] "the mouse is scared of the other "
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found another solution that, though longer, may be clearer for other regex beginners:

```
library(stringr)
# Replace first instance of col a in col b with "INTERIM" 
df$b <- str_replace(b, a, "INTERIM")

# Now that the original first instance of col a is re-labeled to "INTERIM", I can again replace the first instance of col a in col b, this time with an empty string
df$b <- str_replace(df$b, a, "")

# And I can re-replace the re-labeled "INTERIM" to the original string in col a
df$b <- str_replace(df$b, "INTERIM", a)

# Trim "double" whitespace
df$b <- str_replace(gsub("\\s+", " ", str_trim(df$b)), "B", "b")


df
a            b
cat          my cat is a tabby and is a friendly cat
dog          walk the dog
mouse        the mouse is scared of the other
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R, split-apply-combine solution:

```
# Split-apply-combine: 

data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$a), function(x){

        b <- paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x$b, "\\s+"))), collapse = " ")

        return(data.frame(a = x$a, b = b))

      }

    )

  ), 

  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL

)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("cat", "dog", "mouse"),
                 b = c("my cat is a tabby cat and is a friendly cat", "walk the dog", "the mouse is scared of the other mouse"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```